# Stepper motor noises change at random

Tags: stepper-motor

I'm having an issue with my stepper motor, while I am aware they should make a noise that is dependent on the current and speed of the stepping, the issue I'm having is the noise is changing. For example, if I tell it to take 5000 micro steps (1/16), 1 every 700 micro seconds, perhaps after 500 steps, the frequency of the sound changes for a brief period (perhaps 1/4 second) then returns to what it was.

The typical sound is a fairly high pitched whine, the "different" sound is a slightly lower pitched sound.

The reason I ask is that I am having accuracy issues with this stepper, it is attached to an axis and if I move it 5000 steps forward, then 5000 steps backward, in some cases (not all) it is not in precisely the same position.

The power supply used is just a regular computer PSU (I had one spare) and the connector is providing 12V at upto 40 amps, the manual on the PSU states that the current is regulated to within 5% and the volts may fluctuate by upto 120mv, could this fluctuation be causing the issue? If so, how can I rectify this?

I'm working with this stepper motor: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13656 and this driver: http://www.robotshop.com/ca/en/pololu-single-bipolar-stepper-motor-driver.html

Comment: Sounds like it is skipping steps. You are probably going faster than the motor can keep up with (it loses torque as it goes faster because of inductance) - especially if you are using microstepping, maximum torque is gained by doing half-stepping or possibly full-stepping depending on the motor. Try running at a lower speed and see if your accuracy improves.

Comment: @TomCarpenter, That was my initial thought, but it does it at different speeds too.

Comment: Definitely you miss steps. just going slower is not enough. You must use position profile- accelerate and decelerate instead just jumping between 0 and max speed. Adjust voltage to 24V, it will allow higher speed and better current regulation. You have a potentiometer there- make sure you allow maximum current. remove the load...

Comment: You don't mention WHAT you are programming that is creating those steps? Are you using a computer or microcontroller which may be intermittently going off handling interrupts or doing other business?

Comment: @RichardCrowley, its a Raspberry Pi (one of the older models, I forget which). The Pi isn't doing anything else, other than idle OS tasks.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum, I can't easily adjust the voltage to 24, I only have access to 5, 3.3 and 12. Not sure what you mean about position profile accelerate

Comment: I just noticed from the schematic of the driver I'm supposed to be using a capacitor across the motor power supply, which I am not. Could this be causing the issues?

Comment: Assuming you don't have a scope available to monitor the signals from the Pi, can you hook up a little loudspeaker with suitable series resistance to the Pi output and _listen_ to the pulse train to see (or should that be hear) if it is changing frequency?

Comment: Capacitor can be the problem, indeed. I think, it's your best lesson: in the end you solve problems better alone, than any advicors around.

Comment: "its a Raspberry Pi (one of the older models, I forget which). The Pi isn't doing anything else, other than idle OS tasks", only real-time OS can output pulses in a deterinistic way, but just for limited frequency. Have a look to www.linuxcnc.org

Comment: Do the step motor got an regulation on position? I mean even if it is a step motor don't expect precise  movement if you have a regulation....

Comment: @GregoryKornblum, I added the capacitor - alas, no such luck. Same problem

Comment: There was a good comment about pulse generation with operating system. You can't be accurate enough with operating system. In my world even real time OS wouldn't be enough... So first thing i would recommend- use pwm to generate actually constant frequency, then listen to sound. PWM is not good for position control, but you can expect stable sound.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum, I'm not sure I understand - the driver board is generating the signal to the motor coils, the Pi is just sending a STEP command to the driver, what timing requirements are there on that - the speeds I'm operating at should not be close to the limit of the driver which is 1uson both the down and up edges. Surely timing is not so critical here? Similarly, I'm not convinced its an acceleration profile problem either, the change in frequency is random, and occurs multiple times during the 5000 steps, I even implemented a trivial profile, and it did not fix the problem

Comment: In fact, timing is critical. I will try to describe what is going on inside the stepper, but you should better go to wikipedia first. So in the stepper there are, say, 50 magnets and set on coils located certain way. The way they are located allow steps. Full step is defined by current in both phases, positive or negative. So there are four full steps per magnet. Microsteps are actually positions in the middle, when current on phase A and phase B are sine and cosine of certain angle.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum, I understand that timing is critical when pulses are sent to each coil, however a signal from the pi should result in the correct pulses sent from the driver to the coils - the Pi only sends one signal per step, not one per step per coil (or more).  It looks like my problem may be overheating - I've noticed that when there is power to the motors and they are not moving, they click at random. The only thing I can see from the docs is overheating or vaulting. The latter shouldnt be an issue with the capacitors and 12V supply, and I have a heatsync for the former

Comment: So when you make a step (or microstep) the field inside the motor moves. For now assume it moves momentarily. But the rotor cannot move momentarily. In fact, if the motor is not moving, it takes to accelerate, move and decelarate, and then to go a little back. What happens is that rotor follows the field created by phases. But to follow it must be in the movement already. So your first mistake is that you don't create velocity profile, which would gradually accelerate. But it's not enough. Your pulses must fall at exact timing, because if they don't, the rotor may stop following. Then the moto

Comment: Overheating is the result of high hold current. One thing they do is to reduce current once motor stops.

Answer (score 2):

Because "5000" steps one way and then "5000" the other doesn't result in the original position, it's indisputable that you're missing steps.  A could of ideas to narrow it down:

- Try without micro-stepping.  Repeat the 5000 step exercise with full steps.
- Change the speed. You might be right on the edge of a resonant speed, which can cause the change in pitch you describe.
- And yes, definitely use a trapezoidal speed profile as another suggested already.  Going from stopped to 1428 steps/sec is an abrupt start for sure.

Comment: what? Motor are first-order system, they can't change speed instantly therefore putting u(t) command will not result in any problems....

Comment: @MathieuL Perhaps true on paper but practical experience with some of the low-cost drivers suggests differently.  We're talking about a $5 driver board here.  Microstepping (particularly smaller like 1/4 or higher) is not perfectly linear and I've seen it cause exactly the step loss the OP is describing, especially under load.